# Nginx - sending a static file for a specific location

Tags: http, nginx, nginx-location

I'm using nginx as a proxy (with `location /`) and trying to serve a static image for hotlink protection redirects under another location block. The following is what I am using to try to serve the image. I've moved the `root` directive outside of the `location` block which was necessary for nginx to build a proper path for some reason.

```
location = /hotlink.png {
    autoindex off;
    try_files hotlink.png hotlink.png
}
```

However, when I look at the log, it is still looking for an index.html by appending the URI to the root path: `{root}/hotlink.png/index.html`.
I simply want it to only send the file **{root}/hotlink.png** when **/hotlink.png** is matched and that's it.

Why is it still looking for an index with `autoindex off`? How can I fix this or is there a better way to handle this case in general?

Comment: Remove the `try_files` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith That is what I initially had. Without `try_files` it seems to be skipping the block altogether and falling back the `location /` block

Comment: Is `hotlink.png` a real file?

Comment: Yes, it is a real file

Answer (score 0):

After changing gears and coming back to this, I got it working by simply moving the `autoindex off` directive outside of the location block as well. It works with **or** without the `try_files` directive. I left it out for terseness and to avoid redundancy

```
root /path/to/static/files;
autoindex off;

location / {
   # proxy
}

location = /hotlink.png {}
```